# React Native - Stack navigation when back handler is used

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple app with a stack navigator. Which navigates like

`Screen A --> Screen B --> Screen C --> Screen D`

I have added a back handler in Screen B like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}
```

It is working as expected on Screen B. When navigated to C or D, the hardware button won't cause navigation back to B or C respectively. Instead, it seems to fire the handleBackButtonClick in Screen B.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: You must define `BackHandler.addEventListener` once, in root component of your app. Seems like you defined it in several places

Comment: I have defined `BackHandler.addEventListener` only in Screen B. Should I move it to the root `App` component and keep `handleBackButtonClick()` in Screen B?

Comment: Look at the implementation in the docs of RN https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler

Comment: Yes, in root of app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Navigation keeps the previous screens rendered. So you need to make sure that the back handler is only enabled in the focused screen.

The official docs cover it.

For v4: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-android-back-button-handling.html

For v5: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/custom-android-back-button-handling.html

I think in your case the code could be simplified:

```js
handleBackButtonClick = () => {
  // If this screen is not focused, don't do anything
  if (!this.props.navigation.isFocused()) {
    return false;
  }

  // Do what you're doing
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue ,i.e backhandler was trigeering the previous screens backhandler code.

SO what i did was checking for any existing backhandlers and then manually removing it in componentDidMount , rather than trusting the componentWillUnmount for that component..

```
componentDidMount(){
if (this.backHandler) // checking if backhnalder exists from previous screen
    this.backHandler.remove();//removing it
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { this.handleBackButton() });// adding the new backhandler

}
```

Hope this helps, otherwisae feel free to ask any doubts